# SSl handshake issue when using AWS secretmanager for password store in RDS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jdeps, secret-manager

We are using AWS RDS for for our persistent store and using secretmanager for password rotation and storage. It is also encrypted with KMS.

We have a spring boot app which is deployed on ECS fargate and using following dependency :-

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws.secretsmanager/aws-secretsmanager-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws.secretsmanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-secretsmanager-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And using following properties :-

```
# datasource.username=secretId
datasource.driverClass=com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerPostgreSQLDriver
# datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc-secretsmanager:postgresql://example.com:5432/database
```

**Note :- we are using jdeps and jlink to create our custom runtime**

And following are the modules that we are using :

```
Java.base,java.desktop,java.instrument,java.management.rmi,java.naming,java.prefs, java.scripting,java.security.jgss,java.sql,jdk.httpserver,jdk.jfr,jdk.unsupported
```

Now with this configuration it has worked fine for months and we also took it to production. **But from this month we started getting ssl handshake issue, we haven't updated spring boot or secretmanager jdbc version**

Not sure what caused it but either adding `**jdk.crypto.ec**` or adding -**Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2** solved the issue.

Please help me that why this issue started occuring as we haven't done any changes and why the above fixes solved it.
Thanks

Comment: ```we started getting ssl handshake issue, we haven't updated spring boot or secretmanager jdbc version``` means they probably upgraded AWS secretmanager, 1.0.5 is from 2020 you are using very old version. better to stick with latest. ```jdk.tls.client.protocols``` probably pushing secret manager to use the TLS version your app uses. [Check](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/infrastructure-security.html) for the versions of the manager.

Comment: Hi @ozkanpakdil checked the below link but unable to find any upgrade details. Although they do say that they have started upgrading endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With investigation in cloudtrail, we found that the ciphersuite got changed on 26th February from "AES-GCM-SHA256" to **"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"**.
As we were using Java modules for creating our custom hre. We haven't included jdk.crypto.ec explicitly as secretmanager was working fine without it.

Comment: and how did you solve it ?

Comment: Just added jdk.crypto.ec module while creating our custom jre using jlink and it worked.